# How to create method for an array as a property of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods, prototype

Please consider this code in javascript:

```
function Selector() {
    this.Status = "";
    this.Groups = new Array();
    this.Errors = new Array();
}
```

I want to add a method for Groups property of the Selector class and use it for any instance. How can i do this?

Please be aware that i write this code:

```
function Selector() {
    this.Status = "";
    this.Groups = []; 
    this.Groups.myFunction = function(){alert(this.length);  
    };
    this.Errors = [];
}

var selector = new Selector();
selector.Groups = [1,2,3];
selector.Groups.myFunction();
```

But when i set Group property i get error for calling method:

Error: selector.Groups.myFunction is not a function

I prefer to find a way using prototype object.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.Groups.myFunction = function(){};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
  selector.Groups = [1,2,3];
  selector.Groups.myFunction();
```

You are actually initializing a new array and storing it in the selector.Groups property, and since Array object does not have a method called myFunction, you get an error.

You could extend the Array object so that every array has a myFunction method, like this:

```
  Array.prototype.myFunction = function() { alert(this.length) };
```

Which is not a good idea imo, but you're not left with many options since subclassing an array will not maintain the length property in IE :(

See [this link](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/hooray/) for an iframe hack to Array subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work in this way, because in constructor you're assigning an object (array) to class property and extending that particular instance. Then when you're assigning new array, that newly created array has no such method. So your solution can be changed in this way:

```
function Selector() {
    this.Status = "";
    this.setGroups([]);
    this.Errors = [];
}

Selector.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    alert(this.length);
};

Selector.prototype.setGroups = function(groups) {
    this.Groups = groups;
    this.Groups.myFunction = this.myFunction;
};

var selector = new Selector();
selector.Groups.myFunction();
selector.setGroups([1,2,3]);
selector.Groups.myFunction();
selector.setGroups(['foo', 'bar']);
selector.Groups.myFunction();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/6gRCH/)

​But I don't recommend you to use such practice though.
Better is to create a class GroupCollection and encapsulate an array as its property:

```
function GroupCollection(items) {
    this.items = items || [];
}

GroupCollection.prototype.myFunction = function() {
    alert(this.items.length);
};

function Selector() {
    this.Status = "";
    this.Groups = new GroupCollection();
    this.Errors = [];
}

Selector.prototype.setGroups = function(groups) {
    this.Groups.items = groups;
};

var selector = new Selector();
selector.Groups.myFunction();
selector.setGroups([1,2,3]);
selector.Groups.myFunction();
selector.setGroups(['foo', 'bar']);
selector.Groups.myFunction();
```

​[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/6gRCH/2/)